# Check whether image file exists, Robot-Framework, Selenium2Library

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I would like to know, if it is possible and how to check, whether an element, which is supposed to display a picture, does really show the picture.

The picture is in `<img src=..>` and within the same domain.

Comment: This is not possible through pure Selenium. You are essentially doing a link check. See this http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/ and this http://siking.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/simple-web-crawler/ for some ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your goals are. I think it's safe to assume that if your code does everything right (ie: the URL is correct, and css rules don't cause the element to be hidden) that the browser will do what it's supposed to do and show the image. Of course, if you're on the testing team that is actually testing the browser itself, that's a different problem.

So, assuming that the browser is behaving correctly, here are a couple of suggestions:

1. You can use the [Page should contain image](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Page%20Should%20Contain%20Image) attribute to verify the element is in the DOM.
2. You can use the [Get Element Attribute](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute) keyword to get the value of the `src` attribute, and then use the [Get](http://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/#Get) keyword of the [requests library](http://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/) to verify that the url returns a 200 status code.
3. You can use the [Element should be visible](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Element%20Should%20Be%20Visible) keyword to verify that the css rules allow the element to be displayed.

Here is a complete working example:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Selenium2Library
| Library | RequestsLibrary

*** Variables ***
| ${TEST_PAGE} | http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/hovers
| ${BROWSER}   | chrome

*** Keywords ***
| Assert an image is visible
| | [Arguments] | ${element id}
| | [Documentation]
| | ... | This keyword fails if the given image element is not visible.
| | ... | Three checks are performed: that the element is on the page,
| | ... | that selenium thinks the element is visible, and that the 
| | ... | src attribute of the image points to a resource that is 
| | ... | accessible. 
| | 
| | # Step 1: verify the page contains the given element
| | Page should contain image | ${element id}
| | 
| | # Step 2: verify that the element is visible
| | Element should be visible | ${element id}
| | 
| | # Step 3: verify the src attribute of the image is accessible
| | ${img src}= | Get element attribute | ${element id}@src
| | Create session | img-src | ${img src}
| | ${response} | Get | img-src | / | # URL is relative to the session URL
| | Should be equal as integers | ${response.status_code} | 200
| | ... | image url '${img src}' returned unexpected status code '${response.status_code}'
| | ... | show_values=False

*** Test Cases ***
| Example of test to verify an image is visible
| | [Documentation]
| | ... | Verify that the first image on the test page is visible
| | 
| | [Setup] | Open browser | ${TEST_PAGE} | ${BROWSER}
| | Assert an image is visible | //div[@class='figure']/img
| | [Teardown] | Close All Browsers
```

Comment: This is great! However, how exactly does the `${variable.something}` work? Also, why do you use `|` in your code, whereas I use just spaces? It's not the first time I saw this.

Comment: @Qwerty: I use pipes instead of spaces because I think it makes the tests more clear. It can be hard to see the difference between one space or two, or between a tab and a space in some circumstances. The `${variable.something}` is called extended variable syntax. It treats `variable` as an object, and `something` is an attribute on that object. This is documented in the user guide.

Comment: Is there any drawback to not running this step `Should be equal as integers`

Comment: @Freddy: the only drawback is that if the response isn't a 200 (eg: a 404), the test could think that the image is visible (because the DOM element is on the page) when the actual image is not (because the URL is incorrect)

Comment: @Bryan: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the element visible aspect, you can also check via javascript that the image element is actually rendered by the browser and not some missing image icon being shown. You either execute the javascript using Selenium2Library or wrap that Selenium2Library javascript keyword call into a custom keyword to make it more readable.

http://watirmelon.com/2012/11/27/checking-an-image-is-actually-visible-using-webdriver/

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is a little old, but I just found another way to do it without Requests Library:

```
*** Variables ***
${avatar} | css: span.avatar_circle > img

*** Test Cases ***
Check Avatar From WordPress
| [Documentation] | Check if the user image is ok
| [Tags] | avatar | noncritical    
| Click Element | ${avatar}
| Wait Until Page Contains  | Latest Blog
| Page Should Contain Image | ${avatar}
| Element Should Be Visible | ${avatar}
| ${src}= | Get Element Attribute | ${avatar} | src
| Go To | ${src}
| Wait Until Element Is Visible | css: img
| Go Back
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no Robot Framework library which would test that an image is actually displayed. There are a few options:

1. Look into integrating Sikuli with Robot Framework. There are some guides out there which will guide you step by step though the integration. Once you have Sikuli working with Robot Framework, take a screenshot of your image and compare it to the base screenshot. I think this is your best option.
2. There are other tools which do the visual image comparison. For instance, [Needle](https://github.com/bfirsh/needle) is written in Python so if you have some Python skills you could write a library around Needle functionality.