# Robot Framework - Selenium - how to check if image loaded completely

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I want to check if an image is completely loaded on a page using Robot Framework.
I've tried with two keywords

1. Wait for condition |  return arguments[0].complete, //Image xpath
2. Execute Javascript | return arguments[0].complete | ARGUMENTS | //Image xpath

But these are not working. What am I missing?

I went through these two answers which are not specific to Robot Framework.

- [Wait for an image to be fully loaded Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655802/wait-for-an-image-to-be-fully-loaded-selenium-webdriver)
- [Check whether image file exists, Robot-Framework, Selenium2Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532798/check-whether-image-file-exists-robot-framework-selenium2library)